# How to use self variables from one class in another class

Tags: python, pyqt, self

I am somewhat new to both python and pyqt5, and I am basically trying to create one window, have that window open another window from a button, and have that new window be able to communicate with values from the old window (like self.variable defined lists or dictionaries, etc).

I was hoping to use two separate classes in order to keep my code organized, however, I'm finding the use of self with these two classes difficult. I tried calling the method I am interested in from the other class, but I need a self.variable found in the **init** method in order to complete the code (which makes sense). I created two windows from two classes, and the second window opens when the push button from window 1 is pressed.

```py
import csv
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from functools import partial

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Window"
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 500
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 150

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
        self.setFixedSize(self.width,self.height)

        layout2 = QGridLayout()
        label2 = QLineEdit()
        layout2.addWidget(label2)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Enter")
        layout2.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.setLayout(layout2)
        self.show()
        self.Button()

    def Button(self):
        self.button2.clicked.connect()

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Main Window"
        self.left = 300
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 300

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
        self.setFixedSize(self.width,self.height)
        #self.setFixedWidth(self.width)

        layout1 = QGridLayout()
        label1 = QLineEdit()
        layout1.addWidget(label1)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Push")
        layout1.addWidget(self.button1)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.onClick1)

        self.setLayout(layout1)
        self.show()

    def onClick1(self):
        Window()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm wondering if I need to play with inheritance or something to get these to work? The only problem is I already have basically all of my classes inheriting from some pyqt5 class. I also noticed that I needed the "Buttons" method in "Window" in order for the second window to stay up. I don't know if this is necessarily what I want, but it works for now. Could someone help me figure out the best way to transfer data between two windows in two classes. I was debating using QDialog, or working on inheritance. But if you have other suggestions I am all ears. In this example, maybe help me find a way to type something in the second window line edit, and have it appear on the other one. Or something similar.

Comment: It’s very hazy what you want here, but presumably you want to pass (a reference to) the `MainWindow` when creating the `Window`.

Comment: @DavisHerring yes that was my complicated way of saying just what you referred to. But thankfully I figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own.
Lets say in my Main Window I have: **self.variable**

If I want to use this in another class, from the first class I would call the new class like this: **NewWindow(self.variable)**

Then, the NewWindow **init** method would look like this:

**def __init__(self,variable):**

**super().__init__()**

**self.variable = variable**

Then you should be able to refer to this variable in the new class and have it change **self.variable** for the old class as well.